# rotate object in open gl without drowing the object again

Tags: opengl

I want to rotate an object in OpenGL without drawing again, to save time. 
In the init method i want to draw the picture and then only rotate it according to mouse events.

Here is the full method:

```
 gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 gl.LoadIdentity();     
 gl.Rotate(camera_angle_v, 1.0f, 0.0, 0.0);
 gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_POINTS);

 //Draw

 gl.End();
```

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL doesn't work this way fundamentally. The frame you're rendering in is essentially a 2d array of pixels. When you draw an image, it changes the values of some of those pixels to create the image for you. Once something's been drawn, it will stay there until you clear it. OpenGL doesn't keep track of what you rendered in the past (except for the pixels it fills in the frame), so it can't do any transformations on anything but the triangle/line it's currently rendering.

At the beginning of your draw method, you clear the frame (reset all the pixels to the clear color). You have to redraw the object after that. It's how OpenGL works and it's very fast at it. On a modern GPU, you can draw millions of triangles each frame and still maintain 60fps. If you don't clear the frame at the beginning, the image will be drawn on top of the old frame and you'll get a hall-of-mirrors sort of effect.

If performance is an issue, consider learning more modern OpenGL. What you're using right now is immediate mode OpenGL, which was part of the OpenGL 1.0 specification back in 1992. In 1997, OpenGL 1.1 introduced vertex arrays, which provides a significant speed boost for large amounts of vertices since there's only one method call for all the vertices instead of one method call per vertex. And with each new version of OpenGL comes more optimized ways of drawing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to draw the object again - that's how OpenGL works.

Each frame gets rendered from scratch based on the current scene geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Well...  If you're using immediate mode, I guess you can use display lists and call glRotate accordingly.  Though as Robert Rouhani said, the technique you're using is ancient (And what 99% of online tutorials teach you).  Use VAO (or even better, VBO) to draw the object.

Comment: what is VBO or VAO can you send me links about this issue.

Comment: Hard to find good ones, but these 2 are pretty decent and will give you a good start.  http://www.swiftless.com/opengltuts/opengl4tuts.html
http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/